# Having string replace all words after x with y

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

Having string, how can I replace all words, special characters, numbers, what ever is next after x with y.

Example:
Input:

```
String test = "Hello @\"Thomas Anderson\" how are you? Today is 06/13/2013 com month day year !! \"example of date\"";
String x = "com";
String y = "word";
```

Wanted Output:

```
String test = "Hello @\"Thomas Anderson\" how are you? Today is 06/13/2013 com word word word word word";
```

**Rules**

concatenation of special symbols it count as 1 (a.g. !!, @!? ...);

string inside quotes count also as 1 word (a.g. "yahooo ohoo hoho" ...);

if there are more x than 1 then consider the first one and all rest after it as words;

Comment: It would be nice if you paste what work you've done till now..

Comment: *what ever is next after x with y.* ,Where is **X, Y** ??

Comment: @Azad Thats just example -)

Comment: End of your string looks like `... com month day year !! \"example of date\"` but after replacement you have `... com word word word word word`. Shouldnt there be seven `word`s at the end of result?

Comment: @RoshanJha, I know that is possiblie to do with regex code but since im not expert nor good java user so I was thinking about adding 3 space after x word and then split string and work with 2nd part of string where are all words to replace but it would be not nice code.

Comment: @Pshemo, since there is concatenation of special symbols it count as 1 `!!`, and string inside quotes count also as 1 word

Comment: @Azad, just finish to edite post, now it should look more nicly, atlast hope so.

Comment: @Tony that is quite important information and should be included in question.

Comment: @Pshemo, added rules and i do apologize

Comment: @Tony No need to apologize. Correcting question and saying "thanks" is enough :)

Comment: @Tony What in case of empty quote? What should be replacement result for `""!!"`? `word` or `word word`?

Comment: @Pshemo, I didnt consider that case, probably since its in quote then it will be only 1 word. Edite sorry didnt look good, in that case it should be 2, 1 for quote and 1 for special symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easy and most important possible to do it in one line with regex if regex would support non-fixet length look-behind mechanism, but unfortunately there is problems with it in Java. You can do it in few steps

```
//our data
String test = "Hello @\"Thomas Anderson\" how are you? Today is 06/13/2013 com month day year !! \"example of date\"";
String x = "com";
String y = "word";

//splitting string into parts before and after 'x' word
int brakePoint = test.indexOf(x) + x.length();
String prefix=test.substring(0,brakePoint);
String suffix=test.substring(brakePoint);

//in part after `x` replacing quotes OR set of non-white-space characters with 'y'
suffix = suffix.replaceAll("\"[^\"]+\"|\\S+", y);

//result
System.out.println(prefix+suffix);
```

output

```
Hello @"Thomas Anderson" how are you? Today is 06/13/2013 com word word word word word
```

In my regex `\"[^\"]+\"|\\S+`

- `\"[^\"]+\"` part tell regex to search quotation mark `\"` character then one or more characters that is not quotation marks `[^\"]` and again quotation mark `\"`

OR (`|`)

- `\\S+` which means at least one character (`+` quantifier) that is not white-space `\\S`

Oh, maybe this will be interesting: order of these parts is important because we want regex to search quotes before it will consume them with non-white-space matching.

Comment: Could you be so kind to explain regex code.
I've got doubts it.
If string start with " and there are more than 1 " or spacebare?

Comment: @Tony I included explanation of regex in answer. In case you need more info just ask.

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] split = test.substring(test.indexOf(x) + x.length()).split(" ");
StringBuilder builder= new StringBuilder();
for (int i=0; i<split.length; i++) {
   builder.append(" " + y);
}
test = test.substring(0, test.indexOf(x) + x.length()) + builder.toString();
System.out.println(test);
```

Tested it, it works.

**EDIT** for the words between the quotes:

- do some regex based preprocessing of the sentence. Find pattern that matches it (e.g. \".*\") and make it one word (y).

Comment: not working, first `line x.length` shouldnt be`line.length()` and 3rd line `i<split.size()` should not be `i < split.length` ?

Comment: Fixed it, it works now.

Comment: Yes, it does work but it gives you 8 words =S

Comment: Well then, there is some work for you, too! :)

Comment: Thanks, my idea was similar but much longer. Tomorrow I'll do my part, thank you!

Comment: I've edited my answer. So you know how to proceed.